# Generating a random string

Tags: magento2, random

Is there a core class (preferably a framework class) in Magento 2 that can be used to generate random strings? Length of the string is not important.
I don't want to reinvent the wheel and write my own.

Comment: `magento\vendor\magento\framework\Math\Random.php` function `getRandomString`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can use `Magento\Framework\Math\Random` with the `getRandomString` method ;)

In the same class you also have `getRandomNumber` and `getUniqueHash`

Comment: fast and effective. Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a Magento specific method to do this. In PHP 7 you have `random_bytes($length)`. You can use it to create a human readable string by using `bin2hex(random_bytes($length))`

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php

Answer (score 0):

using core Magento\Framework\Math\Random class

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Math\Random;
```

in your class:

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Random $mathRandom,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->mathRandom = $mathRandom;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}

$randNumber = $this->mathRandom->getRandomNumber($min, $max);
$randString = $this->mathRandom->getRandomString($length, $chars);
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this exactly what Raphael said?

Comment: I just used it in my project and here I tried give more detailed info so some less experienced devs will get idea easily.